# Rolling your own application monitoring

Tags: .net, performance, nancy, application-monitoring

I want to monitor endpoint requests to my API as well as response time. I looked at New Relic and others but it's way too expensive.

So I have an idea to just log all requests in my database - simple table with Verb, Url, and total response time.

Is this a bad idea? Good? Will this severely impact my application's performance?

Comment: `Is this a bad idea?` Not really. `Will this severely impact my application's performance?` Depends on how you do it. This question is a little to broad to answer, I suggest you lookup on how to monitor application performance.